# AWS Elastic Beanstalk folders in a .Net project

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Dump Question!

Where do I need to add the .ebextention and .elasticbeanstalk folders in a .net project?  Sorry, .Net is not my normal Language, so still trying to find my feet.

from my current boot strapped VS project, the structure looks like:

```
TestProject(project root eg ...\source\repos\TestProject)
|- TestProject.sln
|- TestProject(.Net code goes in this folder)
   | - bin 
   | - App_start
   | - Models
   | - Controllers
   | - Views
   | - Scripts
   | - Content
   | - Global.asax
   | - Web.config
   | - ...
```

Would I add the EB folders in the Project Root folder or in the folder where the .net code is located?

Answer (score 0):

`.ebextention` and `.elasticbeanstalk` Should be in the `TestProject` folder, i.e project root folder.